# How do I get my Sierra pci express card configured and working?

Tags: networking, drivers, hardware, pci

I need to get a Sierra Wireless AirPrime MC7354 mini-PCI Express card working with Ubuntu server 14.04. The card has been activated on the Verizon network and I'm now trying to get the card configured on the Ubuntu side.

My fundamental problem is that the card is not exposing a network interface (eg. `wwan0` or similar), and while recognized by the OS, it only shows up as a USB device. I have searched the forums quite thoroughly, but found no meaningful help through a related Sierra card thread.

The Sierra Wireless MC7354 datasheet is [here](http://www.sierrawireless.com/productsandservices/AirPrime_Wireless_Modules/Essential_Modules/~/media/Data%20Sheet/AirPrime_datasheets/Sierra_Wireless_AirPrime_MC_Series_Intelligent_Embedded_Modules.ashx), and you can find the tech specs [here](http://developer.sierrawireless.com/Resources.aspx#&&filter=Devices-eq-%28018262A4-D411-41B5-9FD9-87C79E622F86%29)

The device is recognized by the OS and `lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1199:68c0 Sierra Wireless, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04ca:004b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

And `modinfo sierra` shows:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/sierra.ko
license:        GPL
description:    USB Driver for Sierra Wireless USB modems
author:         Kevin Lloyd, Elina Pasheva, Matthew Safar, Rory Filer
srcversion:     C5D0FAB85FF8A5FE30B851A
alias:          usb:v413Cp8133d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0F3Dp68A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0F3Dp68AAd*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v1199p68A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6893d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6892d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v1199p6891d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v1199p6890d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v1199p6880d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v1199p685Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6859d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6856d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6855d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6853d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6852d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6851d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6850d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p683Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p683Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p683Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p683Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p683Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6839d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6838d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6835d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6834d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6833d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6832d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6821d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6820d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6816d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6815d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6813d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6809d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6808d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6805d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6804d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6803d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p6802d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0029d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0028d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0027d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0026d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0025d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v1199p0023d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v1199p0301d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0120d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0112d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0021d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0019d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0224d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0024d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0022d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0220d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0020d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0218d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0018d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1199p0017d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v03F0p1E1Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v03F0p211Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v03F0p1B1Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0F3Dp0112d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        usbserial
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        00:A5:A6:57:59:DE:47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           nmea:NMEA streaming (bool)
```

And `modinfo sierra_net` shows:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/sierra_net.ko
license:        GPL
version:        v.2.0
description:    USB-to-WWAN Driver for Sierra Wireless modems
author:         Paxton Smith, Matthew Safar, Rory Filer
srcversion:     896313DAA9C61C842F37412
alias:          usb:v0F3Dp68AAd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in0B*
alias:          usb:v0F3Dp68AAd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in0A*
alias:          usb:v0F3Dp68AAd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in07*
alias:          usb:v1199p68AAd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in0B*
alias:          usb:v1199p68AAd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in0A*
alias:          usb:v1199p68AAd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in07*
alias:          usb:v0F3Dp68A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in0B*
alias:          usb:v0F3Dp68A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in0A*
alias:          usb:v0F3Dp68A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in07*
alias:          usb:v1199p68A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in0B*
alias:          usb:v1199p68A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in0A*
alias:          usb:v1199p68A3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in07*
depends:        usbnet
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        00:A5:A6:57:59:DE:47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

Finally, `ifconfig -a` shows the `eth1`, `lo` and `p5p1` interfaces (the motherboard has two NICs). I (obviously) need the card to present itself as a network interface in order for our applications to work. I also noticed that there are no ttyUSB* devices in `/dev` and I'm not sure why this is the case.

I am relatively new to Linux (but not at all to OSs) and don't really know where to go from here. What I DO know is that this model doesn't support Direct-IP as some other models do. I have also searched the SW support site, but most of the docs relate to writing drivers to interface to their device. Some of the specs mention the Gobi project, but it's been really hard to make head-or-tail of what direction to go with so little info available and the lack of knowledge on my part.

Comment: Try with installing common wifi drivers: sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree

Comment: Appreciate the help! I did as instructed and rebooted the system, but everything is as it was before (ie. no change that I'm aware of). Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: Reinstall them : sudo apt-get --reinstall install ...

Comment: No change. There must be a driver - most likely Gobi project or similar - that I'm meant to (compile) and install. Would really appreciate any guidance into possible next steps.